# How to pass case ID to redirect case detail page after clicking on save button in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to redirect a page to "Casedetail Page" by passing Case ID in the page reference method after clicking on save in the VF page . Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

for the standard case detail.

```
public PageReference redirect(){
   PageReference p = new PageReference('/'+case.id);
   return p;
}
```